# How did Mraize get an Aviar?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

As seen [here](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/262-oathbringer-glasgow-signing/#e8807) Mraize has an Aviar. The problem is that First of the Sun, the planet that Aviar come from, does not have a Perpendicularity, as stated in Arcanum Unbounded. This being the case, how did Mraize get to First of the Sun to get an Aviar?

Comment: Agreeing with @Chris 's answer - *Arcanum Unbounded* never stated First of the Sun does not have a perpendicularity, it stated it doesn't have a *Shard*, and therefore why and how the perpendicularity came to be is a mystery.  It should be noted, the perpendicularity is in the same exact place that the aviar get their powers - whether that means the birds are retrievable or can travel it themselves is just one of many many other questions (is the area so violent because of the perpend? is that effect guarding the planet from something?).

Comment: @Radhil It's worth noting that to an extent, even that isn't accurate.  It seems like Brandon's statements somewhat contest that.  https://wob.coppermind.net/events/256/#e8606  It's a bit weird, since Autonomy seems to have many avatars, so it's not clear what counts as a "shard"; but it seems like we could absolutely conclude it's _influenced_ by a shard heavily, even if a shard doesn't fully reside on the planet.

Answer (score 4):

I remember reading an interview with Brandon Sanderson where somebody asked a simliar question regarding Mraize's Aviar. (I can't seem to find the source). Brandon States: "If it's called an Aviar, it's origin is First of the Sun."

Edit: In Arcanum Unbounded, I found this regarding First of the Sun:

> I have not been able to discover why, or how this perpendicularity exists. There is certainly no Shard residing in the system. I cannot say what is happening, only that this feature must hint at things that occurred in the past of the planet. There is likely Investiture here somewhere as well, though I have not yet had a chance to investigate First of the Sun myself. The area around the perpendicularity is extremely dangerous, and the few expeditions sent there from Silverlight have not returned.

So there is definitely a Perpendicularity on First of the Sun, but we don't know why. I guess Mraize was able to risk it and grab an Aviar around the perpendicularity.